# JSON.parse unexpected end of data while retrieving response from express server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, express

Client-side code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/tkb',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,

        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }

    });

});
```

Server-side code:

```
controller.listAll = function(req,res) {

    Tkb.find({}, (err,tkbs) => {
        if (!err) res.json(tkbs);
        else res.json({"status":"error"});
    });

};
```

However while retrieving the response, console's network tab on firefox shows me:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

The client expects a json and he's indeed receiving a json. What's the problem?

PS: The response headers shows that the response was a 'application/json'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the Network tab, in the response body, what do you get?

Comment: It's already expecting JSON data so it runs a parse on it. You're essentially JSON.parse'ing twice. Use `res.send` here instead of `res.json`

Comment: I've already tried using `res.send` instead of `res.json` but didn't work.

Comment: I just figured out that the body has:
`{"_id":"579120e474f3462140532825","userId":"blablabla@example.com","tkbValue":15,"isValid":true,"tkbStatus":"blocked","timeStamp":"2016-08-05T12:44:15.999Z"}`

Comment: I don't think that there is a problem with that... :/